# Sharepoint List Comments Showing Duplicate Entries with wrong user profile

Tags: sharepoint-list, version-comments, microsoft-forms, power-automate

I'm using MS Forms to submit a response that goes through Power Automate for 2 point approvals which then information is stored in the Sharepoint list.

Issue #1: when approvers make any comments, in SharePoint list the comments column showing duplicate entries for first approval.

Issue #2: the Second approver using different profiles to approve the request and make comments but as you see that Comment Test Friday has the same user profile as the first approver.

I'm using versioning comments and appending multi-text column for comments

[image]

Comment: Hi actually I managed to fix this issue by using Sharepoint Comments Associated to an item rather then approvals comments